# How to display all customers in a queue in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

So I am writing a c# console which uses a queue to display people in a line. Here is the code:

```
 customers.Enqueue("Jim");
                    customers.Enqueue("Bob");
                    customers.Enqueue("Susan");
                    customers.Enqueue("Liz");
                    customers.Enqueue("Mary");

                    Console.WriteLine("The number of the people in line at the bank is: ");
                 
                    Console.WriteLine(customers.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("The names of those in line at the bank are: " + customers.Peek());

                    customers.Enqueue("Andyn");
                    customers.Enqueue("Rhonda");


                    customers.Dequeue();
                    customers.Dequeue();
                    customers.Dequeue();
                    Console.WriteLine("The number of shoppers now in line is:  " + customers.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("The shopper currently first in line is: " + customers.Peek());

                    Console.ReadKey();
```

It works well, the only issue is when trying to display the names of the people in line, it only displays Jim. I am wondering how to display the others in the line as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach loop

```
foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(customer);
    }
```

result

```
Liz
Mary
Andyn
Rhonda
```

Comment: Technically you should click the up arrow if an answer is useful, and the check mark if an answer is the one you used.. Multiple answers might be useful (and should be upvoted) but you can only mark one as the one you used

Answer (score 1):

Queue implements IEnumerable, which means you can pass it to `string.Join` to create a single string of all elements joined by a common delimiter:

```
var q = string.Join(",", customers);
```

You can then print this out